# conditionalPanel seems not working at shinydashboard?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

`ConditionalPanel` seems not working with `shinydashboard`
the `input` variables are working as shown, but I just can't turn off the `slideInput` under the `conditionalPanel` chunk.

quite odd to me, please advise.
Here is my top example

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- 
  dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = ""),
    dashboardSidebar(
      checkboxInput("chk", label = "checkBox",value = FALSE ),
      conditionalPanel(condition = "input.chk ==TRUE",
                       sliderInput("slide", label = "test", min = 0, max = 10, value = 5))
    ),
    dashboardBody(
      textOutput("result"),
      textOutput("checked")
    )
  )

server <- 
  function(input, output, session) {
    result <- reactive(ifelse(input$slide >5, " greater than 5", "smaller than 5"))

    output$result <- renderText(result())
    output$checked <- renderText(input$chk)

  }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few hours of searching, the answer turned out to be really straightforeward.

```
condition = "input.chk ==1"
```

and solved my question.